# Shortcuts conflict between sublime text and textmate bundle

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate, textmatebundles

I install sublime text 3 and this bundle for mathematica: https://github.com/dehowell/mathematica-tmbundle.

However, when I text edit under the Mathematica mode, I have shortkey conflict issues mainly with three commands, `Documentation for Current Word (control + H)`, `Execute current statement / selection (shift + enter)`, and `Execute current document (command + R)`. All these 3 shortcuts have been already taken by default in sublime text. For example, `(control + H) is replacement` in sublime.

I tried to modify the user keymap in sublime text, but it does not work. I think the right way is to modify that bundle posted on GitHub.

Can anyone help me how to fix this? I want to use this textmate bundle because the bundle for sublime text is really bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the shortcuts if you set `keyEquivalent` in the corresponding .tmCommand file to another value.

The original shortcut for "Documentation for Current Word" can be found at this line: https://github.com/dehowell/mathematica-tmbundle/blob/master/Commands/Documentation%20for%20Current%20Word.tmCommand#L15

The syntax is easy, just use set whatever letter / key you want and use one / two / three of the following modifiers: `^` (Control), `~` (Option), `@` (Command)